# Customizing selected ListboxItem

Tags: c#, templates, windows-phone-7, listbox, telerik

I have a ListBox (actually, i have a Telerik's RadJumpList, but afaik it is inherited from ListBox) with custom ItemContainerStyle. Each item contains a rectangle (tile) and 2 strings. So far, it works okay by default: when i'm selecting an item, color of strings is changing, and rectangle has const color.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
        <Grid Margin="0,0,12,12">
            <Rectangle
                x:Name="SlotTile"
                Width="99" Height="99" Fill="Gray"/>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
                <TextBlock 
                    FontWeight="Black" 
                    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}" 
                    Text="{Binding Title, Converter={StaticResource ToUpperConverter}}" />
                <TextBlock 
                    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}" 
                    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}" 
                    Text="{Binding Information}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

What i want to do now is to customize selected item: tile's color should be changed, while color of the strings should be the same.

I'm trying to set a custom style, using VisualStateManager, but i have no idea how to get rectangle's and string's color.

```
<Style x:Name="MySlotStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Grid 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName=""
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty=""
                                            />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unelected">
                                    <Storyboard>

                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

So, the question is how to set DataTemplate's properties from the Style.

EDIT: uploaded a sample: http://1drv.ms/1cJrjZ4

EDIT2: i extracted (and modified a bit) a style from checkbox: http://pastebin.com/2JV7d5We
They are describing the control inside of the ControlTemplate.

So, i planned to get rid of DataTemplate and move everything to the Style.Template.ControlTemplate. Now, when i'm trying to create a Template binding to a new property (color of the rectangle), it says "the member fill is not recognized".

```
<Style x:Name="TestStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Grid Margin="0,0,12,12">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            ****
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SlotTile" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Description" Storyboard.TargetProperty="TextForeground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource BlackBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                            <Rectangle
                                x:Name="SlotTile"
                                Width="99" Height="99" 
                                Fill="{TemplateBinding Fill}"/>

                            <TextBlock 
                                x:Name="Description"
                                Foreground="{TepmlateBinding TextForeground}"
                                Text="{Binding Title}" />

                            ****
                        </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should edit a copy of the `ItemContainerStyle` style and put your grid that acts as your container inside it. Then you can edit the `VisualState.Selected` storyboard and set the target as your `Rectangle` and the `TargetProperty` as `Fill`.

Here is the XAML code for the `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<Style x:Key="ItemContainerCustomStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SlotTile">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid Margin="0,0,12,12">
                        <Rectangle
                            x:Name="SlotTile"
                            Width="99" Height="99" />
                        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

EDIT: you could even simplify it by using the `Border` container element from the default style. Thus you can remove the `Grid` and `Rectangle` elements.

```
<Style x:Key="ItemContainerCustomStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Border Width="99" Height="99" x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i have also 2 strings "on top" of rectangle/Border, where can i define them and their color in simplified version?

Comment: If these 2 strings (TextBlocks?) need to appear outside the border that has the background color when selected, just add a new container (Grid for example) that surrounds the Border element.

Comment: Not outside, but "on top", just like Wp tiles. I want to control the color of the tile itself (a Rectangle in my sample) and the color of both TextBlocks, when ListItem is selected. So, i have at least 2 custom variables for selected state.

Comment: In that case, you just need to place them in the ItemTemplate. BTW, did you look at the WP Toolkit HubTile control?

Comment: I want to understand how this customization works. I don't need much stuff, just styling of selected item - that's it.

Comment: Take a look at the code in the question: i already tried to use a ItemTemplate, but i have no idea how to customize the Rectangle and TextBlocks color. They are defined in the DataTemplate, so how can i access them from the Style?

Comment: One more time: i have a custom DataTemplate (with Rectangle and 2 TextBoxes), and i want to customize the state (Selected, for example) of it. How to link a Style and DataTemplate?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no easy way to do that, because both templates reside in different XAML namescopes. But you can do that programmatically, check out this article: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/09/how-to-access-named-control-inside-xaml.html

Answer (score 0):

Can't you set those properties by name?

```
<ColorAnimation
          Storyboard.TargetName="SlotTile"
          Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill"
          ...
          />
```

[How to customize the WP7 ListBox Selected Item | Part1](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-customize-the-wp7-listbox-selected-item--part1-control-template)

[How to customize the WP7 ListBox Selected Item | Part2](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-customize-the-wp7-listbox-selected-item--part2-visual-states)

Comment: Nope, that didn't help. If to set them as you mention, i cant see any item at all. Also, Grid inside of ControlTemplate is confusing me a bit.